# Module PIL has not attribute "Resampling"

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, resampling

I have run the same code(with packages I needed) before and it worked, not sure what's happening now. This show the error,
`AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'Resampling'`. Probably it's small issue, but I can't figure it out, I am working in databricks.

Comment: Please add your code and the full error so we can help you.

Answer (score 29):

I had the same problem. The easy way is use the old version of Pillow.

```sh
pip install Pillow==9.0.0
```

And your code should work.

Note: You can also use

```sh
pip install --ignore-installed Pillow==9.0.0
```

If for some reason, pip is refusing to install it. Note, however, that it can break dependencies, so use it only as a last resort.

Comment: Doing this gave yet another error: 
AttributeError: module 'PIL.TiffTags' has no attribute 'IFD'

Comment: works on colab.

Comment: I would not recommend using outdated libraries. Not only will you miss out on improvements, but there are security concerns, and it makes it more likely that you'll run into compatibility issues with other libraries. It's much better to just update your code, as aposch72 explains in their answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72346841/1450294

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem and found that I need to replace `PIL.Image.Resampling.BICUBIC` with `PIL.Image.BICUBIC`.
I am using pillow version 7.1.2

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('image.png')
im2 = im.resize((512,512),resample=Image.BICUBIC)
display(im2)
```

Answer (score 12):

I find that forcing the use of a particular Pillow version may break other packages.

Another solution that works for any Pillow version and avoids deprecation warnings is to insert the code:

```py
  import PIL.Image
  if not hasattr(PIL.Image, 'Resampling'):  # Pillow<9.0
    PIL.Image.Resampling = PIL.Image
  # Now PIL.Image.Resampling.BICUBIC is always recognized.
```

Comment: This seems it might help people developing libraries they want to keep compatible with old code. But for most applications, it's better for developers to be aware of what versions of libraries they're using, and just write code that works with those versions.

It's good to get into the habit of creating virtual environments for development, install the latest versions of libraries, and use `pip freeze` to find out what those versions are, so they can be used for production. This is a pretty good place to start: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/

Answer (score 9):

The resampling enums were seemingly added in [Pillow 9.1.0](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/releases/tag/9.1.0) (released 3 days ago) via [this pull request](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/5954).

I would imagine your Databricks environment has a different verison.

Answer (score 7):

my way to fix it:
pip install --ignore-installed Pillow==9.3.0

Comment: That is a copy (with different version since it was 8 months ago) of a previous answer. Please, edit to clarify how this answer is different, and better, than previous answer.

Comment: This version is what worked for me with fastai, without the `--ignore-installed` though.

Answer (score 4):

Same happened when I upgraded some module. I just restarted runtime and it helped.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, `pip install Pillow==9.1.0` is suitable for my code

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to downgrade the `Pillow` library, you can try to install the latest `matplotlib`:

`python3 -m pip install matplotlib==3.7.1`

Answer (score 2):

install matplotlib==3.7.1

This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Resampling enum (and other new enums) can be added here.
https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stubs/Pillow/PIL/Image.pyi

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33944379)

Answer (score 1):

If you've just installed a Python program with `pip` and it raises this error, it's probably because of a conflict with something you've previously installed. In this case `pip install Pillow==9.0.0` did not work for me (and it may break something else).

Creating a clean venv for that program should fix it:

```
$ mkdir frobnicator
$ cd frobnicator
$ python -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip install frobnicator
(venv) $ frobnicator ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue occur in Google Colab.

I first installed Pillow:

```
!pip install pillow
```

After that I still got the error, until I restarted the Runtime. Once the runtime was restarted, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same issue, so I went with simplest solution by
TADA!@! removing it. also it can be fixed with changing it to Image.BICUBIC. results are just the same for me. working code with same valid results.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).