# Jupyter Notebook - AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'Resampling'

Tags: python, pytorch, python-imaging-library, fast-ai

Was working on a ML project when suddenly my jupyter refuse to work on the first step to import fastai.vision.all

the error is as follow:

[image]

It didnt had this issue prior and I am lost how to solve this.

Comment: What version of PIL you have? You can try installing Pillow 9.1.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module PIL has not attribute "Resampling"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71738218/module-pil-has-not-attribute-resampling)